# Can I get a count for each of a list of domains?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to do a terms filter query to get the number of documents I have for each domain in a list of domains:

```
GET /myindex/_count
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
                 "domain": ["w3.org"]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Returns 25. I have a list of a couple thousand domains and would like to do this all in 1 query. Is that possible? I've tried:

```
GET /myindex/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "terms": {
          "domain": [
            "w3.org",
            "google.com",
            ...,
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but that gives me 1 number (whereas I need them broken down by each domain), e.g.:

```
w3.org: 25,
google.com: 143,
...
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` does not return count for each matching term found, it will show you how many matching docs are found, basically hits in elasticsearch terminology. To get the numbers with each term you found you have to use `aggregations`, more data available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

For your particular case you have to use `Terms Aggregation`, more data available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Your query will look like this

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "terms": {
          "domain": [
            "w3.org",
            "google.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations":{
    "domain_count":{
      "terms":{
        "field": "domain"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response would look something like this, where `doc_count` and `key` inside `buckets` is your required result.

```
{
    ...

    "aggregations" : {
        "domain_count" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 46,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "w3.org",
                    "doc_count" : 100
                },
                {
                    "key" : "google.com",
                    "doc_count" : 52
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you are using `_search` end-point instead of `_count`.

If you don't want to limit your query for particular domains like `w3.org` or `google.com`, you can give a `match_all` query. It will give you all possible `domain` values with their `doc_count`.

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations":{
    "domain_count":{
      "terms":{
        "field": "domain"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a multisearch but w/ a count?

Comment: @kristen by `multisearch` if you meant [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) then yes, you can do it.

Comment: yes, but is there one that uses _count rather than _search?